# Напечатать в столбик числа от 1 до 100 в питоне

Tags: python

Напечатать в столбик числа от 1 до 100

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i)
```